# Magento 2.4.5 Upgrade Compatibility issue representJson() doesn't exist in 2.4.5p1

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.5p1, uct

I have upgraded my Magento2 application to 2.4.5p1. When I run [Upgrade compatibility tool CLI](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/upgrade-compatibility-tool/use-upgrade-compatibility-tool/run.html?lang=en), I'm getting below error in the report for my custom module :

> Call method 'Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface::representJson' that does not exist on version '2.4.5-p1

**My Implementation:**
`$this->getResponse()->representJson($data);`

**Observations:**

1. I have followed same implementation as it is used in following vendor files,  module-checkout/Controller/Cart/UpdateItemQty.php,  module-paypal-captcha/Observer/CaptchaRequestToken.php
2. I have updated doc block for method and class as suggested [here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/upgrade-compatibility-tool/reporting/error-messages.html) and re ran report but issue is still not addressed.

Any help or inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @RohanHapani: As of now. We have raised Magento support ticket. Will share inputs after discussion with Magento support.

Comment: okay thanks....

Comment: Any news from support?